# Is it possible to know the size of a @ValueSource for @ParameterizedTests?

Tags: java, junit5

Given the following sample test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {1,2,3})
void shouldPositiveNumber(int n) {
   Assertions.assertTrue(n > 0);
}
```

Is there a way to know the size of the `@ValueSource` so that I can also check its size?
`@ValueSource` it's just an example, I was thinking about the possibility of external sources.

Finding nothing, I thought about incrementing a static variable and testing its value, sorting the tests appropriately, but it seems a bit too cumbersome and wrong.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {1, 2, 3})
@Order(1)
void shouldPositiveNumber(int num) {
   ++size; 
   Assertions.assertTrue(num > 0);
}

@Test
@Order(2)
void shouldThreeElements() {
   Assertions.assertTrue(size == 3);
}
```

***EDIT***

I have a csv file with a list of product codes. It is necessary to check that:

- the number codes are all positive
- the size of the list must be 100

I am seeing how JUnit5 works from the documentation and I was translating the control like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = "product.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
void shouldPositiveCode(String name, int code) {
   Assertions.assertTrue(code > 0);
}
```

`numLinesToSkip = 1` because the first line is the header.

So I'm trying to figure out how to also verify the number of records present. Is the procedure completely wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to know? It sounds like you're either abusing `@ValueSource` for something it is not intended for, or you are trying to test your test, which is an odd thing to do. If the former, consider describing your actual problem, instead of asking about your perceived solution (a so-called XY problem), if the latter, then just don't do that.

Comment: Because I need to verify the exact size of a codelist. I edited, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: You should probably just read the CSV in your function body, then, and forget `ValueSource`. Even if you could make it work, it'll be weird hack that's hard for others to understand.

Comment: That is not what @ValueSource (and other sources) are for: they are intended to provide multiple independent values to run a single test with different inputs (multiple test cases). It sounds like what you want to have is a single input value that consists of multiple values, or in other words: a single test case.

Comment: @Noah yes, the initial written test case does exactly that: I use a method to read the CSV and after execute the necessary assertions. I had misunderstood the use of JUnit sources thinking I could replace, in my case, the method with the `@CsvFileSource`.
@MarkRotteveel  thanks for the clarification. I will avoid this misuse of sources.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another test into your class that reads the csv inside the test method and checks the number of rows with data.

```
@Test
void shouldHave100Records(){
   int numberOfRecords = {method reading csv and returning number of records}()
   Assertions.assertEquals(100, numberOfRecords);
}
```

The first test remains the same as you have mentioned:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = "product.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
void shouldHavePositiveCode(String name, int code) {
   Assertions.assertTrue(code > 0);
}
```